# Laravel naming conventions pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have two table with relationship many to many:

```
products
product_categories
```

So how do I name the pivot table correctly?.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, are you trying to create models for the pivot tables? `protected $table = post_users` there is no `post_users` table in your list of tables.

Comment: @Remul Yes I have a pivot table model

Answer (score 2):

If there is no particular reason to create different category tables for product and news, I think you should create many-to-many polymorphic relations.

If I went with many-to-many rather polymorphic, I would have created my pivot tables like so

```
categories_products
categories_news
```

In your relation functions, you can determine the pivot table name. The example in Laravel documentation:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'role_user');
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the name of category: product and news ?

Comment: If you create many-to-many polymorphic relations category tabel's name should be categories and relation table's name should be categoryables. If you chose many-to-many use your current tables' names.

Comment: But so I still have to declare ```protected $table``` in my model right?

Comment: Yes, but not relations tables' names. Just the data tables' names like protected $table = news in News model, protected $table = products in Product model, protected $table = categories in Category model. Read the documentation, it's very clear.

Comment: I don't understand yet, why should I use ```protected $table = 'news'``` in mode New.php. I don't need to do that. I mean I have to declare eg: ```protected $table = 'news_news_category'``` in model NewsNewsCategory

Comment: I gave you everything you need, and if they didn't help, go to Laravel documentation and Youtube.